# google api to get particular users google page review

Tags: node.js, google-maps, google-api

I want to fetch the  particular user's google page review and rating when he login to my app, I read the documentation of Google Bussiness API 
https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/prereqs and https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/review-data
I have submitted my project for whitelisted, my main  concern is that can i get the  particular user's google page review and rating when he login to my app and how can I do this

Comment: May i know how you get account id and location id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all you need to white list your google my business api for whatever project you are working on in your project as its private api. Google my business api will work on the locations associated with your account so make sure you verified the LOCATIONS from any account you know. Follow steps mentioned in below documentation URL to set it up: https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/prereqs After the setup and etc you will automatically understand the account id and location id.

i am providing the api that will help you to get the fetch the review

1.get account details: [https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts?access_token={access_token}](http://%20https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts?access_token=%7Baccess_token%7D)

2.you will get the accoutID from step 1 ,and then get location Id [https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/{accountID}/locations?access_token={access_token}](https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/%7BaccountID%7D/locations?access_token=%7Baccess_token%7D)

3.you will get the accoutID,location_id from step 1 and step2 then finally you will get the review [https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/{accountID}/locations/{location_id}/reviews?access_token={access_token}](http://first%20of%20all%20you%20need%20to%20white%20list%20your%20google%20my%20business%20api%20for%20whatever%20project%20you%20are%20working%20on%20in%20your%20project%20as%20its%20private%20api.%20Google%20my%20business%20api%20will%20work%20on%20the%20locations%20associated%20with%20your%20account%20so%20make%20sure%20you%20verified%20the%20LOCATIONS%20from%20any%20account%20you%20know.%20Then%20you%20can%20try%20out%20the%20api%20call%20you%20mentioned%20in%20OAuthplayground.%20%202)%20Follow%20steps%20mentioned%20in%20below%20documentation%20URL%20to%20set%20it%20up:%20https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/prereqs%20After%20the%20setup%20and%20etc%20you%20will%20automatically%20understand%20the%20account%20id%20and%20location%20id.%20%20i%20am%20providing%20the%20api%20that%20will%20help%20you%20to%20get%20the%20fetch%20the%20review%20%20get%20account%20details:%20https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts?access_token=%7Baccess_token%7D%20%20get%20location%20Id%20https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/%7BaccountID%7D/locations?access_token=%7Baccess_token%7D%20%20get%20review%20https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v4/accounts/%7BaccountID%7D/locations/%7Blocation_id%7D/reviews?access_token=%7Baccess_token%7D)